# WASD not working for quicktime event

Tags: metal-gear-rising-revengeance

Do I just mash random WASD keys or do I actually have to mash them in a circle W-D-S-A?  Many times I am getting frustrated by getting caught by the monkey enemies and mashing WASD and not being able to break free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to mash any/all of those keys as fast as possible. It doesn't take much to break free, even on hardest difficulties. Focus less on precision and more on spamming as many presses as you can.